# Make Wi-Fi fast again (on my Ubuntu, like it was on Windows)

Tags: networking, wireless, windows, internet, samba

When I used Windows 7 on my notebook, Wi-Fi worked fine, it gave me 11 mega bytes per second speed. But now, on Ubuntu, I only have 130 kilo bytes per second via samba, and 1-2 megabytes via torrents -- it's up to 85 times less than it was earlier! But when I use Ethernet connection, I have about 10 mega bytes via samba, and up to 5 megabytes via torrents -- this is my internet provider speed maximum.

Help me please to setup my ubuntu wi-fi connection to get my speed back!
Here is diagnostics info about my networking: https://pastebin.com/kSYxZqgK